# To know in advance when one is a niddah

Tags: halacha, technology, time, medicine, niddah

The gemoro and shulchan aruch has much to say about 'vestos', way to find out in advance when one will be a niddah, which rarely work today. There are modern methods which do work: does one have to use them? Especially since the 'old' ones don't work anymore.

Comment: Although I ask the question, and am sure one has to use them. I am really asking if any rov has given an opinion on this.

Comment: What methods are you referring to?

Comment: @Double AA Ovulation tests. There are also other tests. I think the 'knai bosem' does talk about it. I believe that after ovulation she has to (conceive or) become a niddah in about 14 days.

Comment: A woman is supposed to keep a veset if she always becomes a niddah after the same amount of time following going off hormonal birth control pills (for example if she always starts her period 2 days after going onto the placebo)